# Прошу привести пример, как c помощью JS найти на странице текст получить класс родительского объекта

Tags: javascript, dom

На странице есть "искомый текст",
на выходе должен быть объект (переменная) с классом "родительский элемент"
пример кода в котором надо найти "искомый текст"
Проблема в том, что классы генерируются динамически и искать по названию класса бессмысленно.
Но текст (часть текста\слово) неизменны.
Поэтому элементы необходимо получить именно отталкиваясь только от текста.

```html
<div class="родительский элемент">
 <div class="контейнер2">
  <div class="контейнер3">
  <p>искомый текст<p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чтобы получить просто текст из элемента можно воспользоваться свойства `textContent` или `innerHTML`:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('.block3 p');
    
console.log(element.textContent);
console.log(element.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="block2">
        <div class="block3">
            <p>искомый текст</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

чтобы получить родительский элемент необходимо использовать свойство `parentElement`

```
console.log(element.parentElement);
```

Однако, если вы не знаете где находится (в каком блоке) соответствующий текст, то придется пройтись по всем блокам, заглядывать в их дочерние блоки (использовать `querySelectorAll('*')`) и искать текст описанным выше способом (использовать `textContent`)

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('*');

for (const element of elements) {
    if (element.textContent.localeCompare('искомый текст') == 0) {
        console.log("исходный элемент:", element)
        console.log("родительский элемент:", element.parentElement)     
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="block2">
        <div class="block3">
            <p>искомый текст</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Исправил текст вопроса. К сожалению, классы блоков генерируются динамически, количество блоков варьируется и текст (его отрывок) видимо придётся искать именно по тексту, а затем получить уже классы элементов.

Comment: тогда смотрите мой последний код в ответе - это то, что вам нужно